# Regex to catch 3 strings in 6 seconds

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I'm trying to catch 3 or more string in my log-file within a 2 seconds. An examlpe

```
213.240.206.92 - - [22/Apr/2018:16:47:50 +0300] "POST /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2.0" 200 6295 "https://localhost/shop/peach/corral/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
213.240.206.92 - - [22/Apr/2018:16:47:51 +0300] "POST /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2.0" 200 6295 "https://localhost/shop/peach/black/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
213.240.206.92 - - [22/Apr/2018:16:47:52 +0300] "POST /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2.0" 200 6295 "https://localhost/shop/m/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
213.240.206.92 - - [22/Apr/2018:16:47:59 +0300] "POST /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2.0" 200 6295 "https://localhost/shop/choko/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

In the case above I need to catch first three strings because it has 2 sec interval, but not 4th because it has 3 sec interval from previous. I can catch only a string using

```
^<HOST> - .*"POST /\?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2\.0"
```

But it does not work for multiline.

```
^<HOST> -.*"POST /\?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2\.0".*\s.*"POST /\?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2\.0".*\s.*"POST /\?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments HTTP/2\.0"
```

1. How to catch 3 strings within 6 seconds?
2. Do I need correct regex or I able to use my only working regex and put in jail.conf

   maxretry = 3

   findtime  = 6

?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will be option 2 but I'd love to see someone prove me wrong.

Comment: It looks to me that the first three log lines are only 1 second apart each and the last one is 7 seconds later. I'm not seeing the 2 second interval and then the 3 second interval.

Comment: I don't think that regex are the best option for what you want to achieve, since you need to do mathematical computation

Comment: using fail2ban to block this sort of traffic is a bit excessive. Is there really any consequence to a < 2 second interval?

Comment: @danblack, yep, in some cases it could crash my PHP 7.0-7.2 via WP/Woo get_refreshed_fragments long lasting requests

Comment: sounds like an infrastructure problem best solved with good engineering rather than fail2ban.